# AS can't find BottomSheetBehavior_Params, _behavior_peekHeight and _behavior_hideable

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, bottom-sheet, android-layoutparams

I just update my app to Support Library version 24.0.0 and I'm getting some error about BottomSheet Params.
The code:

```
/**
 * Default constructor for inflating BottomSheetBehaviors from layout.
 *
 * @param context The {@link Context}.
 * @param attrs   The {@link AttributeSet}.
 */
public BottomSheetBehaviorGoogleMapsLike(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            android.support.design.R.styleable.BottomSheetBehavior_Params);
    setPeekHeight(a.getDimensionPixelSize(
            android.support.design.R.styleable.BottomSheetBehavior_Params_behavior_peekHeight, 0));
    setHideable(a.getBoolean(android.support.design.R.styleable.BottomSheetBehavior_Params_behavior_hideable, false));
    a.recycle();
    ViewConfiguration configuration = ViewConfiguration.get(context);
    mMaximumVelocity = configuration.getScaledMaximumFlingVelocity();
}
```

Android Studio can't find:

- `android.support.design.R.styleable.BottomSheetBehavior_Params`
- `android.support.design.R.styleable.BottomSheetBehavior_Params_behavior_peekHeight`
- `android.support.design.R.styleable.BottomSheetBehavior_Params_behavior_hideable`

**Any idea where they moved it?**

Comment: I was about to ask this in your github repo :) thanks for the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it! they change its name. Just change the word `Param` for `Layout`.
Like this: `BottomSheetBehavior_Layout_behavior_peekHeight`

More info [in official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/R.styleable.html#BottomSheetBehavior_Layout)

Comment: I need custom BottomSheetBehavior. On tap bottom sheet should open 50% of the screen. But BottomSheet should cover 100% of the screen when dragged. Can you please help me.